# Php removes part of string

Tags: php, string

I have this simple string variable:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM striscie AS previous, striscie AS current WHERE previous.linea=current.linea AND current.ident=$striscia AND previous.position<current.position AND previous.position>current.position-$stops";
```

yet, when I echo or use it, it turns to:

```
SELECT * FROM striscie AS previous, striscie AS current
WHERE previous.linea=current.linea AND current.ident=897524 AND previous.positioncurrent.position-3
SELECT * FROM striscie AS previous, striscie AS current
WHERE previous.linea=current.linea AND current.ident=920173 AND previous.positioncurrent.position-2
```

By deleting the whole part of the string. I tried restarting Apache to no avail. What might it be?

Comment: some charachter inside php vars ($stops is an example) do cut the string maybe

Comment: you can print this inside a `<pre>`

Comment: My problem is that not only the print sees the string like this, but also sql treats it strangely. I count the number of results but it does not find them, and not being able to see the output string I do not know where the problem might lie.

Comment: I managed to fix it blindly, sure it is strange how it mangles the strings.

Answer (score 8):

`<` is being treated as HTML by the browser. Don't blindly output stuff like that.